# Enabling and Setting an Exchange Remote Mailbox using EWS or Graph via API call

Tags: exchange, exchange-2016, web-services, microsoft-graph

I work for a higher Ed organisation and currently we onboard new students to Active Directory and Hybrid Exchange with Powershell scripts.

I am bascially seeking to automate and move the process to a web API operation using Jitterbit or even Mulesoft.

The sticking point I find is that I cannot see how I would do the equivalent to the Powershell cmdlet 'Enable-RemoteMailbox' and indeed 'Set-RemoteMailbox' in either the Microsoft Graph API or Exchange Web Service SOAP API.

It appears that there are many API functions for Manipulating content and folders within a Mailbox but I cannot explictly see how I configure the Mailbox itself.

If this a case of RTFM could some please point me to the FM then !!!!

Otherwise; can I actually invoke a powershell script with an Web Service API call on the exchange server to do this. This feels like a horrid security risk, so any suggestions greatly welcomed !

Comment: To me it is not possible as these deal with mailbox contents.

Comment: @Kael this is what I suspect as well. I was hoping to 'shake the tree' so to speak and see if someone far more knowledgeable would be able to point me in a direction, bit I certainly cannot google up a solution to this currently.

Comment: I can not find anything concrete on this matter and can only assume that this not possible via Webservice API. I am happy to consider this question closed.